# Reading Data From A File - Java

Tags: java

We use `String.split()` to differentiate data. What if my client wants to access data from a file, and the file contains data of books.

Like this: `Book Name = ABC, Author = XYZ, Price = 123`.

Similarly I have multiple entries. What command do I use if I want data from the same file but only of a particular author or price, etc.?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I wanted to know how can I pull content from a text file without actually reading the entire file i.e. If I have data of books stored in one .txt file. But I only want to see books from XYZ author. How do I do that? Hopefully I've cleared things up.

Comment: @user3646145 Is the file formatted in some way (e.g. CSV, etc.)?

Comment: @user3646145 And really, I think the fastest way would be to search as you read through the file, unless there are some tricks you can do with random-access files that I am not aware of.

Comment: No, it isn't. Plain text file.

Comment: So is the example you gave pretty much exactly how lines are formatted?

Comment: Yes. I have 20 books data stored. I have 7 books from the same author and I wanted to retrieve those books by simply filtering the field of authors.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @user3646145 Are you always going to be filtering by author? Or will your search criteria change?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch As of now, nothing yet. Since I'm new to Java. I have only retrieved the .txt file. But I want to filter it by a category i.e. Author.

Comment: @user3646145 Yeah, ncmathsadist's answer works if you want to do that. Based on your situation you can also consider different collections, but that's the general answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to read data from a file. It reads the file line-by-line. For each line, split it and store it as needed:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadTextFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileFullPath = "C:\\Temp\\data.txt";

        /** verify that file exists */
        File checkFile = new File(fileFullPath);
        if (!checkFile.exists()) {
            System.err.println("error - file does not exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }        

        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileFullPath));

            /** keep reading lines while we still have some */
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } //end main()

} //end ReadTextFile class
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple `Book` class.  Make an `ArrayList<Book>` and suck the contents of the file into it. You can then pull stuff out of the array list easily.

Comment: Object Oriented programming.

Comment: @user3646145 I'd be a little wary if the file were really really big though. And I'd go more a `HashMap`, as finding things from that would be *significantly* faster. Unless you need to change your search criteria, in which case have fun...